# simpler way to set value based on offset in assembler - 8051 code

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, uart, 8051, baud-rate

I'm trying to invent a version of the following code that runs using fewer clock cycles. This is because I'm making a reliable UART to data converter for two 8051 chips since both their serial ports are taken.

Ideally, I want the serial port running at a 38400bps or higher speed and I plan to have the data as 16 bytes per transmission in the following format:

```
Byte 1: x0h 
Byte 2: xrh
Byte 3: xrh
Byte 4: xsh
Byte 5: xsh
Byte 6: x5h
Byte 7: x6h
Byte 8: x7h
....
Byte 15: xEh
Byte 16: xFh
```

So basically the high nibble in each byte is user data, and the low nibble is either the data offset, or if the offset is low enough (but higher than 0), then it will contain nibbles for the sender and receiver address. In the end, the addresses are 1 byte a piece (maximum 256 senders and 256 receivers).

This is the code I have so far, but it takes at least 24 clock cycles to run it which might stop me from reaching 38400bps speed. This is because on the 8051 with a 22.1184Mhz crystal that I'm using, (according to https://www.8051projects.net/wiki/8051_Software_UART_Tutorial) it turns out according to calculation:

```
1 bit time = (((crystal/baud)/12) - 5) / 2
= ((22118400/38400/12) - 5) / 2
= 21.5
```

But if i removed the -5 part in the equation then the number is 24. I want to try to make this code work with fewer clock cycles. Anyone know what I can do here?

```
  D equ P2 ;(high nibble is data)
  TXCT equ 30h ;transmit nibble counter
  ADDR1 equ 31h ;receiver address low nibble
  ADDR2 equ 32h ;receiver address high nibble
  ADDR3 equ 33h ;sender address low nibble
  ADDR4 equ 34h ;sender address high nibble

  orl D,#0F0h     ;allow incoming data
  mov A,D         ;and check it
  mov R5,TXCT     ;save count and use it as low nibble by default
  cjne R5,#1h,xt1
mov R5,ADDR1  ;replace low nibble of 2nd byte of data with ADDR1 nibble
sjmp xt4
  xt1:
  cjne R5,#2h,xt2
mov R5,ADDR2  ;replace low nibble of 3rd byte of data with ADDR2 nibble
  sjmp xt4
  xt2:
  cjne R5,#3h,xt3
    mov R5,ADDR3  ;replace low nibble of 4th byte of data with ADDR3 nibble
    sjmp xt4
  xt3:
  cjne R5,#4h,xt4
mov R5,ADDR4  ;replace low nibble of 5th byte of data with ADDR4 nibble
  xt4:
  anl A,#0F0h ;discard low nibble from port (we want user data)
  orl A,R5 ;add nibble
  CLR TI
  mov SBUF,A ;send to serial
  inc TXCT ;increment counter
  anl TXCT,#0Fh ;and set to 0 if it goes past 15
  jnb TI,$
```

Comment: You've got 10 times the number of cycles than you calculated to send each byte. Each byte takes 10 bit-times (1 start bit, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit) to transmit through the UART.

Comment: Well my entire code for the whole adapter (which I posted only 1/3 of) when run with the slowest case situation takes up no more than about 50-70 clock cycles. Your statement tells me then that I could actually pull off using 115 kbps if I wanted to just because my grand total number of cycles is less than 80?

Comment: You can save some cycles at the cost of program size by unrolling the first 5 bytes so you don't have to compare `TXCT`. Alternatively, you could use indirect addressing to load the special nibbles.